# What is the plot of following function

Tags: graphing-functions, infinity

What would the plot for $ x^{x^{x^{x^x...}}}$ look like for $x \in\mathbb{R}$?

I think all math-tools try to compute it **recursively** which end up with the error "standard computation time exceeded".

And sory, I could not express it well in the title.

Comment: How often do you repeat the exponents? Right now this is not a function at all!

Comment: It will look like the y-axis.

Comment: I think we only take values if the sequence $x\uparrow\uparrow n$ converges. If my assumption is correct, then for x>1 it does not exist. For x=1, the value is 1. @mimin, continue by cases as I have started.

Comment: @AlbertoTakase What does your double arrow notation mean?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation

Comment: If the power tower $x\uparrow x\uparrow x\uparrow \cdots$ converges, this value can be calculated via Lambert's W-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks something like this:
[image: Knuthpower]

where the even powers converge to the blue line and the odd powers converge to the yellow line. The point where these two converges to the same value is near $0.07$.

As pointed out in the comments, this function is not defined outside $[0,1]$ since the sequence $(x \uparrow\uparrow n)_{n=0}^\infty$ escapes to infinity.

Edit: This function also converges in $[1,e^{1/e}]$ according to StackTD's answer.

Comment: You cut out the $x$ axis.

Comment: How did you plot this?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Mathematica

Answer (score 3):

The infinite power tower $$x^{x^{x^{x^x{^{^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot}}}}}}}}$$ converges only for $e^{-e} \le x \le e^{1/e}$, which is approximately in the interval $[0.0659 \,,\, 1.4446]$.

In that interval, the power tower can be rewritten in terms of the [Lambert W-function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html) which you can then use to have the graph plotted by computer software:

$$x^{x^{x^{x^x{^{^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot}}}}}}}} = -\frac{W\left( -\ln x \right)}{\ln x}$$

[image]

You can also take a look at [this plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20-lambertw(-ln(x))%2F(ln(x))%20for%20x%20from%20e%5E(-e)%20to%20e%5E(1%2Fe)) by WolframAlpha.

Comment: I doubt to select an answer. Your answer is also perfect! Thank you.